# Support Vector Machine with 3 outcomes

Tags: r, classification, svm, cross-validation

**Objective:**

I would like to utilize a classificaiton Support Vector Machine to model three outcomes: Win=1, Loss=0, or Draw=2. The inputs are a total of 50 interval variables and 2 categorical variables: `isHome` or `isAway`. The dataset is comprised of `23,324` instances or rows.

*What the data looks like:*

```
Outcome isHome isAway   Var1   Var2    Var3 ... Var50
   1      1      0      0.23   0.75    0.5  ...  0.34
   0      0      1      0.66   0.51    0.23 ...  0.89
   2      1      0      0.39   0.67    0.15 ...  0.45
   2      0      1      0.55   0.76    0.17 ...  0.91
   0      1      0      0.35   0.81    0.27 ...  0.34
```

The interval variables are within the range 0 to 1, hence I believe they do not require scaling given they are percentages. The categorical variable inputs are `0` for not Home and `1` for Home in `isHome` and `1` for Away and `0` for not Away.

**Summary**

1. Create Support Vector Machine Model
2. Correct for gamma and cost

**Questions**

I will be honest, this is my first time using SVM and I have practiced using the Titanic dataset from Kaggle, but I am trying to exapnd off of that and try new things.

1. Does the data have to be transformed into a scale of `[0,1]`? *I do not believe it does*
2. I have found some literature stating it is possiable to predict with 3 categories, but this is outside of my scope of knowledge. How would I implement this in R?
3. Are there too many features that I am looking at in order for this to work, or could there be a problem with noise? *I know this is not a yes or no question, but curous to hear people's thoughts.*
4. I understand SVM can split data either linearly, radially, or in a polygon. How does one make the best choice for their data?

**Reproducable Code**

```
library(e1071)
library(caret)

# set up data
set.seed(500)
isHome<-c(1,0,1,0,1)
isAway<-c(0,1,0,1,0)
Outcome<-c(1,0,2,2,0)
Var1<-abs(rnorm(5,0,1))
Var2<-abs(rnorm(5,0,1))
Var3<-abs(rnorm(5,0,1))
Var4<-abs(rnorm(5,0,1))
Var5<-abs(rnorm(5,0,1))
df<-data.frame(Outcome,isHome,isAway,Var1,Var2,Var3,Var4,Var5)

# split data into train and test
inTrain<-createDataPartition(y=df$Outcome,p=0.50,list=FALSE)
traindata<-df[inTrain,]
testdata<-df[-inTrain,]

# Train the model
svm_model<-svm(Outcome ~.,data=traindata,type='C',kernel="radial")
summary(svm_model)

# predict
pred <- predict(svm_model,testdata[-1])

# Confusion Matrix
table(pred,testdata$Outcome)

# Tune the model to find the best cost and gamma
svm_tune <- tune(svm, train.x=x, train.y=y, 
             kernel="radial", ranges=list(cost=10^(-1:2), 
             gamma=c(.5,1,2)))
print(svm_tune)
```

Comment: This question is really broad. It's really more of a stats methods question, and at least partly a subjective one at that, i.e. each part could be answered with "it depends." You might have better luck splitting it into discrete questions and posting at [stats.se]

Comment: The thing is if you ask how to do something in R on CV, it gets bumped over to here, or at least that is what my experience has been.

Comment: Sure, but this is several stats methods questions posted as one code question. Maybe if you break out specific code-related pieces of this question, they'll be on topic for SO.

Comment: Questions 1, 3, 4, and the first part of 2 are just about statistical modeling.  If you leave out the second part of 2, I don't see why those questions wouldn't be welcomed on CV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to answer each point, to my opinion you could get different solutions for your problem(s), as it is now it's a bit "broad". You could get answers also from searching for similar topics on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

1. > Does the data have to be transformed into a scale of `[0,1]`?

It depends, usually yes it would be better to scale `var1,var2,..`. One good approach would be to build to pipelines. One where you scale each `var`, one were you leave them be, the best model on the validation set will win.

**Note**, you'll find frequently this kind of approach in order to decide "the best way".

Often what you're really interested in is the performance, so checking via [cross-validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)) is a good way of evaluating your hypothesis.

2. > I have found some literature stating it is possible to predict with 3
   >   categories, but this is outside of my scope of knowledge. How would I
   >   implement this in R?

Yes it is, some functions implement this right away in fact. See the example linked down below.

**Note**, you could always do a multi-label classification by building more models . This is called usually **one-vs-all** approach (more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/one-vs-all-multiclass)).

In general you could:

- First train a model to detect `Wins`, your labels will be `[0,1]`, so `Draws` and `Losses` will both be counted as "zero" class, and `Wins` will be labeled as "one"
- Repeat the same principle for the other two classes

Of course, now you'll have three models, and for each observation, you'll have at least two predictions to make.

You'll assign each obs to the class with the most probability or by majority vote.

Note, there are other ways, it really depends on the model you chose.

**Good news is** you can avoid this. You can look [here](https://medium.com/@ODSC/build-a-multi-class-support-vector-machine-in-r-abcdd4b7dab6) to start.

`e1071::svm()` can be easily generalized for your problem, it does this automatically, so no need to fit multiple models.

3. > Are there too many features that I am looking at in order for this to work, or could there be a problem with noise? I know this is not a yes or no question, but curious to hear people's thoughts.

Could be or could not be the case, again, look at the performance you have via CV. You have reason to suspect that var1,..,var50 are too many variables? Then you could build a pipeline where before fit you use [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) to reduce those dimension, say to 95% of the variance.

How do you know this works? You guessed it, by looking at the performance once again, one the validation set you get via CV.

My suggestion is to follow both solutions and keep the best performing one.

4. > I understand SVM can split data either linearly, radially, or in a
   >   polygon. How does one make the best choice for their data?

You can treat the kernel choice again as a hyperparameter to be tuned. Here you need to look at performances, once again.

---

This is what I'd follow, based on the fact that you seem to have already selected `svm` as the model of choice. I suggest to look at the package `caret`, it should simplify all the evaluations you need to do (Example of [CV](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-estimate-model-accuracy-in-r-using-the-caret-package/) with caret).

1. Scale Data vs not Scale Data
2. Perform PCA vs keep all variables
3. Fit all the models on the training set and evaluate via CV
4. Take your time to test all this pipelines (4 so far)
5. Evaluate again using CV which `kernel` is best, along with other hyperparameters (`C`, `gamma`,..)
6. You should find which path led you to the best result.

If you're familiar with the classic [Confusion Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix), you can use accuracy even for a multi-class classification problem as a performance metric.

Comment: I don't really care for the downvote, but it just seems pointless like this..Is there something wrong with my answer? Does it not address the question? Is it just because the question is too broad? Even if this question gets migrated to CV is still a valid answer IMO.

Comment: When you say look at the performance, what do you mean here? Do you mean doing k-fold cross validation? Also, I don't think there is anything wrong with your answer nor did I downvote it, I am just trying to read through it and understand/implement it.

Comment: I did have a follow up question. When you say label Wins or Losses as `[0,1]`, and likewise for Home or Away. How does this get written within a dataframe? As two separate columns?

Comment: No you build 3 `data.frame`, where you recode the outcome to a binary problem. And you train on each of them the model, so that's why you end up with three models fit.

Comment: And yes, you measure the performance via k-fold, use the correct metrics for your task, i.e. accuracy. You'll have the accuracy on plan A and on plan B, you pick the best (if you need to decide A or B).

Comment: I think I am doing Plan B, use `e1071::svm()` package to predict 3 outcomes. But for Home/Away, it is 2 binary columns.

Comment: No what I meant is, if you have two ideas (ex: A is perform PCA, B is not perform PCA), then you decide to evaluate the accuracy on both, and pick the best one. Anyway, yes you don't actually need to do 3 models.

Comment: The `e1071` vignette, ["Support Vector Machines"](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/e1071/vignettes/svmdoc.pdf), says: "Scaling of the data usually drastically improves the results. Therefore, `svm()` scales the data by default" (page 6).  So the OP's code does scale the features.

Comment: Yes you're correct, I forgot to mention that some algorithm may scale by default. Still, it's nice to evaluate if it's needed in this particular case, probably it wouldn't hurt.